# Cutting out a specific part of an image

Tags: html

[Man with a VR headset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtyRi.jpg)

I need help in figuring out how to cut a specific part of the image as I want to wrap a paragraph around the image in HTML for a project I'm working on. I need to cut out the bottom right of the image and i would be happy for any feedback on this issue. Thank you.

Comment: By cutting, what you mean? You need to add certain text to the right bottom of the image? Is that it ?

Comment: Do you just want to cut off the bottom right of an image and replace it with text?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
 .crop {
        width: 200px;
        height: 150px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .crop img {
        width: 400px;
        height: 300px;
        margin: -75px 0 0 -100px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="crop">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPh0S.jpg" alt="Donald Duck">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

You can use negative margin to move the image around within the